# How to change applications name after starting the applications. windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, services, windows-services

Hey i'm wondering if it's possible to rename a proccess's name after opening it, i'm not talking about display name (the window title), I mean say for example google chrome. If I opened it, it'd be chrome.exe, but is there a way I can change it too chrome2.exe while it still being open?

Comment: You cannot rename an executable while it's in use.  What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound Trying to inject a dll into a process, then inject the same dll into another process with the same name, while first process is open. I don't have the DLL, I open another app that connects to a sever and gets the data to inject the DLL. So when I open the first program and inject it injects the DLL it works fine, but when I open the 2nd program to be injected, the first program dies, at first I thought it was a security thing with the auto injector, but it is not. It's reinjecting into the first process, probably because that's what the dll auto injector finds first.

Comment: @Ramhound I see you have a lot of experience working with windows, if you think you know of any other way too accomplished what i'm trying to do please let me know